# How to get country wise alexa rank of a website using php?

Tags: alexa-internet

I want to get country wise alexa ranking of a specific website using PHP or JAVASCRIPT.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
<?php
    $url='google.com.sg';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
    $rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY)?$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT:0;
    $country_rank=isset($xml->SD[1]->COUNTRY)?$xml->SD[1]->COUNTRY->attributes()->RANK:0;
    $web=(string)$xml->SD[0]->attributes()->HOST;
    echo $web." has Alexa Rank ".$rank." and Country Rank ".$country_rank.".\n";
?>
```

The result will be

> google.com.sg has Alexa Rank 282 and Country Rank 2.

Adapted from [here](http://99webtools.com/blog/php-script-to-get-alexa-rank/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this http://aws.amazon.com/code/AWIS/402

The UrlInfo has a Response Group called RankByCountry that should solve your purpose. Find details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/